# Calculate every possible time range in a specific period using R

Tags: python, r, dataframe

How can I calculate every possible time range in a specific period using R?

**Example**

Time period: 2021-01-01 - 2021-06-30

| startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-03 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-04 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-03 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-04 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-05 |
| ... | ... |

Condition: The start date must always be before or equal to the end date

Any ideas?

Best,
Jannik

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged with ``python``?

Comment: would an answer in python be acceptable to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start = as.Date("2021-01-01")
end = as.Date("2021-06-30")
## get all the dates in the range
seq = seq(start, end, by = "day")
## produce all unique combinations of 2 dates
pairs = t(combn(seq, 2))
## verify they are already correctly ordered
all(pairs[, 1] < pairs[, 2])
# [1] TRUE

## put them in a data frame and convert back to date
## (the `combn` step produced a matrix and lost the Date class...)
pairs = as.data.frame(pairs)
pairs[] = lapply(pairs, as.Date, origin = "1970-01-01")
names(pairs) = c("start", "end")

## examine the first few rows
head(pairs)
#        start        end
# 1 2021-01-01 2021-01-02
# 2 2021-01-01 2021-01-03
# 3 2021-01-01 2021-01-04
# 4 2021-01-01 2021-01-05
# 5 2021-01-01 2021-01-06
# 6 2021-01-01 2021-01-07

dim(pairs)
# [1] 16290     2
```

This doesn't include the range from a date to itself, as in your first row. If you want those included, you could tack them on at the end:

```
rbind(pairs, data.frame(start = seq, end = seq))
```